# Proving a Certain Subset is a CW Subcomplex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I'm having some trouble with a detail in a proof from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (Prop. A.1 on p. 520 for those interested, though I don't think it's relevant): We have a CW complex $X$ and an $n$-cell $e_\alpha^n \subset X$, and the image of this cell's attaching map is contained in a finite subcomplex $A \subset X$. Hatcher claims that $A \cup e_\alpha^n$ is a finite subcomplex, but I'm having trouble seeing why. I'm trying to show that the boundary of $e_\alpha^n$ is contained in $A$ but I'm not getting anywhere. Is it true in general that the closure of an $n$-cell is its union with the image of its attaching map?

EDIT: I'd like to prove this without invoking the fact that CW complexes are Hausdorff, since the book hasn't proven that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely, extremely easy to show a CW-complex is Hausdorff, include it in your proof if you are worried about it.

With this fact, the closure of an open cell $e \rightarrow X$ is the image of $e \cup S^n \rightarrow X$ given by the inclusion of the open cell and the characteristic map on the boundary. This is because $e \cup S^n = D^{n+1}$ is compact, and the image of a compact set is compact which in a Hausdorff space implies closed. This is the smallest closed set containing the image of $e$ since any point in the image of the characteristic map is in the boundary of the image of $e$.

Comment: Makes sense, just figured it was unusual for Hatcher to implicitly be using the Hausdorff-ness of a CW complex in the proof before he formally proves it on the next page.