# Proposition A.1 in Hatcher's AT, the last sentence

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I have a problem with reading the proof of the proposition A.1 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book.

In the last sentence he says $A \cup e^n_\alpha$ is a finite subcomplex containing $e^n_\alpha$. To say like this, we should make sure that the closure $\overline{ e^n_\alpha }$ is a subset of $A \cup e^n_\alpha$. How can I do this? My idea was using that $X$ is Hausdorff, but this does not seem to be the same logic to Hatcher's because he states this Hausdorff property two pages later.

Comment: @JustinYoung The image of $\phi_\alpha$ indeed lies in $A$, but does this ensure that $\overline{e^n_\alpha} \subset A \cup e^n_\alpha$? The closure $\overline{ e^n_\alpha }$ equals $\overline { \Phi_\alpha ( \mathring D ^n _\alpha )}$, which generally _contains_ $\Phi_\alpha ( D^n_\alpha ) = e^n_\alpha \cup \phi_\alpha (\partial D^n_\alpha)$.

Comment: @AlpacaParka The attaching map sends the boundary of an $n$-disk to the $(n-1)$-skeleton of $X$. By induction hypothesis, the image of the boundary of the $n$-disk under $\phi_\alpha$ lies in the finite subcomplex $A$. Now, when you take the closure of $\phi_\alpha(e^n)$, it simply includes the part that gets identified with the $(n-1)$-skeleton. The induction says that part is already contained in $A$, so $e^n\subset A\cup e^n$.

Comment: @Kevin.S Could you explicitly tell me what your induciton says? The induction in Hatcher's proof?
And I still dont' understand why the set $\overline{e^n_\alpha}-e^n_\alpha$ is conatined in the $(n-1)$-skeleton. Can you explain this with more detail?

Comment: @JustinYoung Maybe that is the point I misread. In my opinion, $A \cup e^n_\alpha$ should contain by definition the closure of each cell in it to be a subcomplex. This is the reason why I repeatedly ask about $\overline{e^n_\alpha}$. Is this a wrong way? Then why?

Comment: @JustinYoung Okay, then how do you show that $A \cup e^n_\alpha$ is a subcomplex?

Comment: I get it now! Yes, it looks like you need to get into the weeds of a proof that $CW$ complexes are Hausdorff or, more to the point, that compact subsets are closed.

Comment: Same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3792018/17892

Comment: Consulting May's book "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology", I find the definition of subcomplex I wanted: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/maybook.pdf (see Chapter 10). With this definition, the above fact is immediate.

Comment: In May's definition, it is a theorem to be proved that subcomplexes are closed.